# How do I install .NET system-wide on an arm64 Ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, .net, arm

I'm trying to install .NET runtime 6.0.16 system-wide. I need multiple users on a server to be able to access this from PATH. Generally, Microsoft recommends to use `apt` to install .NET packages -- but this isn't possible for arm64 builds. I can't really figure out how to install .NET system-wide as I'm used to using `apt` to install packages I need system-wide access for.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the manual instructions, just extract the files outside of a home directory (`/opt/` is the recommended place for manual installations) and edit the system wide `/etc/environment` instead of the personal files of a user.

Comment: Yes, here are some corresponding links from Microsoft.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#im-using-an-arm-based-cpu https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#manual-install